# Flatten nested associative array while preserving key value groups

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have deep nested associative arrays structured like this:

```
Array
(
  [id] => 1
  [name] => Noodles
  [nodes] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
          (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Egg
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                )

          )

      [1] => Array
          (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Flour
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                  [0] => Array
                      (
                        [id] => 4
                        [name] => Water
                        [nodes] => Array
                            (
                            )

                      )

                )

          )

    )

)
```

That I'm trying to flatten into:

```
[
    [
        'id'        => 1,
        'name'      => 'Noodles',
    ],
    [
        'id'        => 2,
        'name'      => 'Egg',
    ],
    [
        'id'        => 3,
        'name'      => 'Flour',
    ],
    [
        'id'        => 4,
        'name'      => 'Water',
    ]
];
```

I've tried using recursive iteration, but I can't get it to return all key values on the same dimension to push into a new array:

```
// $data is the incoming structure mentioned above

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));

foreach ($it as $key=>$value) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
```

The above is only printing the last / deepest array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [name] => Water
)
```

How can I best flatten all of these multidimensional associate arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of **$key** are being repeated, so each time **$key** is **id**, for example, the existing value of **$result['id']** is being replaced.

I'm not sure this takes best advantage of the iterator, but try something like this:

```
$tempId = '';
foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'id'){
        if ($value != $tempId) {
            $temp = [];
        }
    }
    $temp[$key] = $value;
    if ($key == 'name') {
        $result[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't ideal due to rigidity of the data structures, but works for now

Comment: Yeah, it's not a general solution, but it illustrates what I meant. Good luck!